# OSx : User appear in /Users but not in Preferences/Users And Groups

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

So I have these users in /Users

[image: cd /Users]

But in Preferences -> Users and Groups some users don't show up.

When I open the command line the the prompt looks like it's shown in the screen shot.

So I have two user names that show in the prompt, and I find that weird. And I just want to know how is that possible, is it safe to delete the "macbookpro"?

I don't think so but I am not sure. I think all the content of my Mac Documents, Photos belong to that user "macbookpro".

`cd ~ | pwd` gives this :

[image: cd ~ | pwd]

Answer (score 0):

You can see which users you really have on your Mac with this command:

```
dscl . -list /Users | grep -v '^_'
```

To see where the home folder for a specific user is, you can use (e.g. for the user "david"):

```
dscl . -read /Users/david | grep 'NFSHomeDirectory'
```

You'll have to see what's inside the `macbookpro` folder to see if it's safe to delete. If you're not able to open it, it probably belongs to the `macbookpro` user. You'll have to either log in as `macbookpro`, or give yourself access to the folder (e.g. `sudo chmod -R g+rX /Users/macbookpro`)

Answer (score 0):

A reason this may happen is because the user does not have a password set. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72949120/ansible-builtin-user-module-not-working-on-macos).